# What causes the error "Not all code paths return a value"?

Tags: c#

```
public string Valid(OleDbDataReader myreader, int stval)
{
    object val = myreader[stval];

    if (val != DBNull.Value)
    {
        return val.ToString() ;
    }
    else
    {
        Convert.ToString(0);
    }
}
```

There is a Error " not all code paths return a value"
please Help

Comment: What do you think the error means?

Comment: @thekip That not all code paths return a value. :)

Comment: Your `else.....` block does **NOT** return any value.... that's what the error clearly says.....

Comment: Dont forget to mark answer as accepted if you got the info you want

Answer (score 3):

You need to read about basic of C functions.

As function returning string value it must return a value in all cases. This includes the else part also.

The reason is if there else part is executed than you need to return string value, but there is no return there:

```
public string Valid(OleDbDataReader myreader, int stval)
    {
        object val = myreader[stval];
        if (val != DBNull.Value)
        {
            return val.ToString() ;
        }
        else
        {
           return Convert.ToString(0); //forgot to write return over her
        }
    }
```

Comment: Or, perhaps better yet in this particular case, C# functions :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo , No .. I think he nailed it with C. I was actually about to answer this myself (a quick glance at my active tags should make you chuckle after reading that).

Answer (score 3):

When you create a function that is meant to return a value, you need to ensure that all possible paths through that function eventually return a value.

In your case, no value is returned if `myreader[stval]` is equal to `DBNull.Value` since it will enter the `else` clause and simply drop through to the end of the function, returning nothing:

```
public string Valid(OleDbDataReader myreader, int stval)
{
    object val = myreader[stval];
    if (val != DBNull.Value)
    {
        return val.ToString() ;
    }
    else
    {
        Convert.ToString(0);
    }
}
```

My own personal opinion is that this would be better written as:

```
public string Valid (OleDbDataReader myreader, int stval) {
    object val = myreader[stval];

    if (val != DBNull.Value)
        return val.ToString() ;

    return Convert.ToString(0);
}
```

In other words, it's often better to provide a default case at the end to ensure this can't happen. I cringe whenever I see code of the form:

```
if something:
    return or exit
else:
    do something else
```

since it's needlessly complex and can lead to exactly the sort of problem described here in your question (as well as indentation hell). Far better (again, this is my opinion but it's backed by way too many years of experience) to use the simpler:

```
if something:
    return or exit
do something else
```