# "File.ReadAllText(String)': Not All Code Paths Return A Value

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I'm sure this is a simple fix but I simply cannot get my head around why I'm getting this error. Any help or pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. I've tried searching previous posts but cannot understand them as I'm fairly new to C#.

Here's a general overview of what the purpose of the program is.

> *A computer program is required to read the daily hours parked by customers and output the hours and parkingFee for each customer to a
>   file. There are 50 entries for customer’s parking hours (integer
>   numbers) stored in a text file ‘hours.txt’. You are required to read
>   the file and store the data in an array, there is no need to validate
>   the data, assume all hours have already been validated between 1-24.
>   Calculate the parking fee for each customer, there is a maximum
>   parking fee of $20.00. Output the hours and parkingFee (to 2 decimal
>   places) to file. Calculate and output the average (to 2 decimal
>   places) of the parking fees to the screen.*

And my code so far as follows.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    const decimal HOURLY_RATE = 2.50m;
    const decimal MAX_FEE = 20.00m; //Capped at S20.00
    string path = @"d:\hours.txt";
    string stringFromFile = File.ReadAllText(path);

    List<int> hours = stringFromFile.Split(null).Select(int.Parse).ToList();
    Console.WriteLine("Hours and fee's parked per person");
    decimal total = 0;
    foreach (int parkingTime in hours)
    {
        decimal parkFee = HOURLY_RATE * parkingTime;
        if (parkFee > MAX_FEE)
            parkFee = MAX_FEE;

        total += parkFee;
        Console.WriteLine("Hours: {0}. Parking Fee: {1}", parkingTime, parkFee);
    }

    decimal average = total / hours.Count;
    Console.WriteLine("Average = {0}", average.ToString("N2"));
    Console.ReadKey();     
}
```

Comment: Your code works fine - and I expect it to, because the only method you have is a `void`, so no return is required.

Comment: The error doesnt make sense though, i think you might have some wires crossed, and this error shouldnt exist in this code

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: @Parrish We aren't anti-homework, we're anti "do my homework for me", which this isn't.

Comment: Voting close because the error cant be reproduced

Comment: @John yeah not trying to sound negative.  I usually try coaxing the solution with a lighter touch if it's for school.

Comment: @Parrish Oh, I see. Sorry - tone doesn't come across well on the Internet :-)

Comment: @RyC I can't reproduce the issue with your posted code, but read through [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343992/what-causes-the-error-not-all-code-paths-return-a-value) to get a gist of what causes it. Essentially, when you get this error, your code will have a flow in a non-void method which doesn't return a value. For example `private string GetName(int i) { if (i >= 5) { return "hello"; } }` will produce this error, because you don't return a value when i < 5.

Comment: @ParrishHusband Yes, this is homework. Sorry if it came across that I wanted you guys to finish my homework for me, but that's not the case.

Comment: @RyC no apology needed, you've clearly done most of what is needed already.  Are you still having the error from the post title?

Comment: @John Thanks again for your input, your help is always appreciated.

Comment: Can you post a few lines of the hours.txt file?

Comment: @ParrishHusband Yes I am still getting the error but I think I've figured out where I've gone wrong. Sometimes I just need another opinion. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @ParrishHusband
 8
24
9
7
6
12
10
11
23
1
2
9

Comment: Maybe look into using string interpolation on your outputs, but great otherwise.